# How to save an image from an Access database to disk using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to export a picture from an Access database, but it gives me an error. I've already tried a lot of things but nothing works.

```
import win32com.client
daoEngine = win32com.client.Dispatch('DAO.DBEngine.120')
db = r"D:\Shared_Folders\Projects_for_programming\Python\ZekBase\db.accdb"
daoDB = daoEngine.OpenDatabase(db)
query = "SELECT picture FROM picture WHERE check IN ('00036')"
daoRS = daoDB.OpenRecordset(query, 2)
daoAttachmentRS = daoRS.Fields["picture"].Value
daoAttachmentRS.Fields["picture"].SaveToFile("D:\Shared_Folders\Projects_for_programming\Python\ZekBase")
daoDB.Close()
```

the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\Shared_Folders\Projects_for_programming\Python\ZekBase\rrr.py",
> line 8, in 
> daoAttachmentRS.Fields["picture"].SaveToFile("D:\Shared_Folders\Projects_for_programming\Python\ZekBase")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'memoryview' object has no attribute 'Fields'

[image]

I think I need to somehow work with ole object...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save MS ACCESS attachments with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126769/save-ms-access-attachments-with-python)

Comment: `daoAttachmentRS.Fields["picture"].SaveToFile` - `"picture"` should be `"FileData"`.

Comment: Is picture an Attachment data type field?

Comment: @June7 re: "Is picture an Attachment data type field?" - Doesn't look like it. IIRC, Attachment fields in DataSheet view look like a paperclip:  "Bitmap Image" probably means that it is an OLE embedded object (.bmp file wrapped with an OLE header).

Comment: Yep. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875177/save-image-to-access-database-as-bitmap-image/38938659#38938659 and http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm

Comment: @June7 - There's also [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19709053/2144390) I wrote 10 years ago. It's C#, but the same thing could likely be done in Python.